# Hacer scroll en un elemento determinado con Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, html5, bootstrap

Estoy creando un chat utilizando php y javascript. Necesito que se haga scroll al final de la última conversación por lo que cree un elemento `span` de nombre "final". Para ello utilicé una ventana modal de Bootstrap. Probé con el siguente código en Javascript, pero no puedo. Probé diferentes códigos, pero se sigue posicionando en el primer elemento del mensaje.

```
 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Chat Messages</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="page-content page-container" id="page-content">
            <div class="">
              <div class="row container d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="box box-warning direct-chat direct-chat-warning">

                    <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="direct-chat-messages" id="ultimo">

                        <?php foreach ($coneccion1 as $co) : ?>
                          <?php if ($co['id_usuario'] == 1) : ?>
                            <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                              <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"> <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Timona Siera</span> <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right"><?= $hola = LongTimeFilter($co['time']); ?></span> </div> <img class="direct-chat-img" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/36/000000/administrator-male.png" alt="message user image">
                              <div class="direct-chat-text"><?= $co['mensage'] ?></div>
                            </div>
                          <?php else : ?>
                            <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
                              <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"> <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right">Sarah Bullock</span> <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left"><?= $hola = LongTimeFilter($co['time']); ?></span> </div> <img class="direct-chat-img" src="https://img.icons8.com/office/36/000000/person-female.png" alt="message user image">
                              <div class="direct-chat-text"> <?= $co['mensage'] ?> </div>
                            </div>
                          <?php endif ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                        

                      </div>
                      <span id="final"></span>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer col-md-12">
          <form id="formchat" class="w-100">
            <div class="input-group"> <input type="text" name="mensaje" placeholder="Type Message ..." class="form-control"> <span class="input-group-btn"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat" id="btnchat">Send</button> </span> </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
const btnact=document.getElementById('activar');
btnact.addEventListener('click',()=>{
 console.log(document.getElementById('final').scrollIntoView(true))

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias agregar el scroll a tu HTML con CSS

```html
<div class="scroll-container"> your elements html </div>
```

```css
/* SCROLL CONTAINER */
.scroll-container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}
/* Track */
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
/* Handle */
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #d6d0d0;
}
/* Handle on hover */
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(160, 139, 139);
}
```

Ejemplo en Codepen

https://codepen.io/nelsoncode/pen/GRZVJvd

Comment: No me funciona ya lo intente